# How to stop cron job from creating attach_pid files?

Tags: java, linux, cron, redhat, pid

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo). I have configured a cron task to run a Jar file via shell script for every 5 minutes. Upon checking the folder (where shell script file is located) after few days, I found that hundreds of attach_pid files were generated. Why does this file getting created and how to stop it?

Comment: Check your script and java app.

Comment: For? @Ipor Sircer

Comment: for creating files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put thoese files in the `tmp` dir instead by puttting a line in you java code:

```
private static final String tmpdir = "/tmp";
```

and then down in your code , where you are creating files , pass the `tmpdir` to the `New` constructor

```
f = new File(tmpdir, fn);
```

Reference code [here](https://www.alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/openjdk-8/jdk/src/solaris/classes/sun/tools/attach/LinuxVirtualMachine.java.shtml)